# Преобразование String в char или присвоение значению String определенного числа int

Tags: java, строки, switch, case

Через JOptionPane запрашиваю пользователя ввести символы +, —, * или /. (Это все сохраняется в переменной String).

И после этого, мне нужно сложить, отнять, перемножить или разделить 2 переменные, в зависимости от того, что ввел пользователь. 
**И вот я не могу понять.** Можно ли как-нибудь преобразоват*ь //либо присвоить какое-либо числовое значение переменной* String так, чтобы компилятор понял что я хочу сложить*// отнять перемножить разделить.*

Comment: несвязанные вопросы здесь принято задавать по отдельности. воспользуйтесь, пожалуйста, кнопкой «задать новый вопрос» для второго из ваших вопросов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно символ в `switch` проверять:

```
String op = "+";
if(op == null || !op.isEmpty()){
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Operation should be present");
}
switch (op.charAt(0)){
  case '*':
    break;
  case '+':
    break;
  case '-':
    break;
  case '/':
    break;
  default:
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown operation: " + op.charAt(0));
}
```

Comment: а в java нельзя сделать `switch(op) case "+": ...` ?

Comment: можно, но тут только один символ требуется обрабатывать, поэтому такой подход.